# Print compiled handlebar template (without data filled in)

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am working on compiling templates from partials using handlebars. Currently, I have the following javascript:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
  fs = require('fs');

var data = {
  title: "Print handlebars tempalte",
  author: "Internet",
  body: "Hi, I am the body"
}

fs.readFile('partial.html', 'utf-8', function(error, source) {
  handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', source);
});

fs.readFile('ignore-keywords.html', 'utf-8', function(error, source) {
  var template = handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(data);
  console.log(html)
});
```

The partial is as follows

```
<div>
  <p>
    Hi, I am a partial!
  </p>
</div>
```

And the template is

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <p>{{body}}</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div>
      <p>
        Written by {{author}}
      </p>
    </div>
    {{> example_partial}}
</div>
```

As you can see in the script, I can print the final, generated html by using `console.log`. However, I want to be able to print the final template without the data filled in. Something like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <p>{{body}}</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div>
      <p>
        Written by {{author}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        Hi, I am a partial!
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to print compiled templates that I should be able to then send to other sources which use this compiled template, fill it with the data and then generate the respective HTML. It is for this purpose that I need to generate the above mentioned templates. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't print or share compiled templates, since they are functions.

When you call `handlebars.compile`, it breaks the template down into strings and replacement tokens, then builds a function at runtime that will concatenate the strings with the proper tokens from the incoming data. Loops (`{{#each}}`) are turned into real JS loops as well.

Unfortunately, neither the simple JSON string algorithm nor the more robust [structured cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) are able to serialize function objects. I'm not aware of anything that can, although some browsers do support a `.toString` on functions that will print the source.

I think you might be able to work around that, though. I would try replacing the `{{` tokens in the `'ignore-keywords.html'` template so they aren't evaluated by handlebars, but exclude the `{{>` token. Do the same thing with your partial template, then invoke the parent template. It should evaluate and include the partial without replacing any of the variables. Swap the escaped tokens back into `{{` and you have a template that can be compiled normally, but already has the partials inline.

Comment: LMAO funny enough I need exactly this in 2022 and then I see it good ol @ssube who answered it. Going to try exactly this ;).

Answer (score 0):

Since Handlebars is JS, you will need to add a JS file to each project/site/app that has globally accessible functions that retrieve your templates from a static location (a known web address) and then generate said templates based on function arguments. Either that or use something like Node.js to build and return these templates server side based on ajax request parameters. Personally I would stick with the former as it simply requires embedding a JS file in whatever application you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ssube answer which gave me the idea this is how I went about it.

Only the relevant code below. My use case was I needed to actually generate the template with data to test *and* generate a final `.hbs` with the tags intact for our team that's uploading it to a separate service. I have every partial in a `partials` directory, and a main file called `tamplate.hbs` that starts the process.

So basically using the logic @ssube mentioned we just do a simple replace of all the `{{` with another character (I chose the caret `^`). Of course we don't want to replace our imports so we ignore the pattern `{{>`.

We then run the template with no data, it pulls all the templates together into one, then we go back through and replace `^` with `{{`. Note just for ease we don't have to replace the ending `}}` since Handlebars just ignores them if they don't have a starting block.

```js
function compileTemplate() {
    // register partials
    const partials = fs.readdirSync('/partials');

    partials.forEach(partial => {
        const partialName = partial.split('.')[0];
        const partialOutput =  fs.readFileSync(`/partials/${partial}`, 'utf8');

        // Strip out the handlebar tags so we can give the templating service an export with template strings intact
        // However we still want to pull in our partials so we ignore {{>. We replace all other {{ with ^ for now.
        const partialTemp = partialOutput.replace(/{{(?!>)/g, '^');

        // Register our exported partial for use.
        Handlebars.registerPartial(`${partialName}`, partialTemp);
    });

    // create the template object
    const templateStr = fs.readFileSync('/template.hbs', 'utf8');

    const exportTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateStr);
    let exportTemplateOutput = exportTemplate();

    // Now add the {{ back we removed earlier.
    exportTemplateOutput = exportTemplateOutput.replace(/\^/g, '{{');

    fs.writeFileSync('exported/export.hbs', exportTemplateOutput, err => {
        if(err) {
            console.err(err);
        }
    });
}
```